# Cannot insert phpBB picture in Gmail message

Tags: image, gmail, phpbb

It's necessary to insert an image from phpBB forum into Gmail message, for example
https://colnect.com/forums/download/file.php?id=569926

but get error:

> We can't find the image at that URL.

On other hand I can insert picture from another phpBB forum, for example https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/download/file.php?id=38919

Сould you help me and tell what is wrong with first picture or forum settings at colnect.com?